# How to not startx in hosted inux CentOS 5.5 ,and how to make full screen

Tags: vmware-server, centos5, graphical-user-interface

Im beginner to VMWare player , im using CentOS 5.5 as the virtual OS and installed the VMWare Player in windows xp 32 bit 
And its working great , but when I like to start the GNUME gui to use x server its starting the GUI desktop right inside the VMWare server 
I like it just to start , and I will connect form out side ( for example with xming x server ) how can I do that ?

Second question is how can I make the VMWare server with the GUI display to be full screen on my desktop ?
Now when I resize the window its getting full screen but the Linux main window remain centered and small . and I like it to stretch full screen

Answer (score 0):

First you should install the VMware tools in the Linux OS.

Then adjust the size resolution in the CentOS screen properties.